# What is remembered set in G1 algorithms used for?

Tags: java, jvm, g1gc

I just read some blogs about G1 algorithm.

The usage of remembered-set is confused to me.

Here is what I think:

Since we can use DFS to walk through every reference from GC-Roots, why do we need remembered-set?

Cause all the blogs to say the reason why we use remembered-set is we don't need to check every region to see if there is an object that is referenced by GC-Roots

Comment: "*Since in generational GC we may need to find all the live objects in a young generation **without traversing the older generation***..."  https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/rts/storage/gc/remembered-sets

Comment: Does that mean every time g1 want to recycle a region, it need to check his remembered-set and every pointer in remembered-set's remembered-set, and if end with a gc-roots, that mean it is not recyclable

Comment: @Michael you are correct, but remembered sets were "born" before G1 became generational, as a matter of fact the size of these sets triggered G1 to become generational.

Comment: @ratsafalig you have it backwards. References are not traversed to the GC roots. References are pointing into the other direction and hence, you can only traverse them from the roots to the objects. Otherwise, garbage collection wouldn't be such an expensive operation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to understand what `Card Table` is first, IMO. How do you scan *only* `young generation` region and clean it, if there are references from `old generation` back to `young`? You need to "track" exactly where these connections are present - so while scanning `young generation` you could clean it without breaking the heap.

Think about it: you can't mark for removal an Object `A` that it is in young generation now, if there is a reference `B` to it, from `old generation`. But remember that right now - you are in the young collection *only*. So to track these "connections" a `Card Table` is implemented. Each bit from this card table says that a certain portion of the old generation is "dirty", meaning *also scan that portion from the old generation* while scanning young.

Why do you need that? The entire point of scanning young is to scan a little piece of the heap, not all. This `card table` achieves that.

`G1` has regions. What if you are scanning `regionA` and you see that it has pointers to some other `regionB`? Simply putting this information in the `Card Table` is not enough. Your card table will only know about `regionA`, and next time you scan `regionB` - how do you know you are supposed to scan `regionA` also? If you don't do that, obviously the heap integrity is broken.

As such : `remembered sets`. These sets are populated by an asynchronous thread: it scans the `card table` and according to that information it also scans where these "dirty" regions have pointers to. It keeps track of that `regionA -> regionB` connection. Each region has it's own `remembered set`.

So when you reach the point that GC needs to happen, when scanning `regionB` you also look at it's `remembered set` and find out that you also need to scan `regionA`.

---

In practice, this is why `G1` became generational : these `remembered sets` turned out to be *huge*. If you divide the heap in `young` and `old`, there is no need to keep the connections between young generations, you scan them all at once anyway, thus taking away the burned on the size of these sets. `G1` wants to keep that `200ms` (default) promise - to do that, you need to scan young generation *all at once* (because there is no connection between regions in `remembered sets` and otherwise heap integrity is gone), but at the same time if you make young generation small - the size of `remembered sets` will be big.

As such, touching these settings is an engineering miracle, IMHO.

Comment: Can i think this way: ```remembered set``` is more exact version of  ```card table``` , since 
 ```card table``` only know which region and ```remembered set``` knows exact address

Comment: @ratsafalig to be frank, no. These are not "versions" of each other.G1 has them both